# How to browse windows network in ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: networking, windows, file-sharing

While trying to access a Windows network it shows:

> Unable to access location, Failed to retrieve share list from server, No such file or directory

How to solve this, and connect with Windows shared folders?

Comment: what do i enter as the hostname and username? is it the name of the computer i want to connect to? what if i do not know it and what to connect to it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

assuming you have installed samba,

on the command line, you can explicity list all shares on a given host  with this command

```
smbclient -L <hostname> -U cashew
```

-U is the username option

This command might be helpful, when nautilus might not list all hosts and shares that are in fact available.

Connect to a SMB share with

```
smbclient //server/share -U user
```

Enter you user password.

You can connect directly with

```
smbclient //server/share -U user%password
```

but your password will show on the screen (less secure).

Once connected you will get a prompt that looks like this :

```
> smb: \>
```

Type "help" , without quotes, at the prompt for a list of available commands.

Comment: So, I can connect to and see smb directories in the terminal, but Nautilus does not show or connect to. This answer only shows how to connect in the terminal, but does not provide how to fix the Nautilus problem. Is there any way?

Answer (score 4):

Be sure to install samba<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

```
sudo apt-get install samba
```

Now try it again.

Answer (score 0):

Run terminal and enter this command-

```
gksudo gedit /etc/hosts
```

and add computer ip address and name in hosts file. Save and exit.

Sample ip and name:

```
192.168.120.65    pankajPcName
```

Thats all.It will solve your issue .

Answer (score 0):

Spent hours trying to sort out this issue, been in any and every post and documentation, but was determined to resolve this issue once and for all, and found the problem.
Went to windows 7 and according to the firewall, the sharing settings been not well configured to accept Linux, but now it is.
So my advice is to built the smb share into Ubuntu (or Linux) and if not successful, try to find the next issue inside windows.

Comment: Can you give a detailed description, on how to `built the smb share into Ubuntu`, please?!